# How to save a `.bat` file with` ANSI` encoding using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, batch-file

The following code is used to create a `.bat` file containing two song names.

```
 listMp3=[]; 

 var elementA = document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("a")
 );

 elementA.download = "file.bat"; 

 listMp3.push("óáã.mp3");
 listMp3.push("ôç.mp3");

 var music='';
 for(var i=0;i<listMp3.length;i++){
  music+=(listMp3[i]+'<>');
 }

 music= music.replace(/<>/g, "%0D%0A");
 elementA.href = "data:text/plain," + music;
 elementA.click();
```

There will be later in the `file.bat` the commands:

```
move óáã.mp3 óáã.mp3
move ôç.mp3 ôç.mp3
```

My intention is to check if these music files are open in another program.

However, these character accents are improperly recorded in the `listMp3`. It is as if the encoding saved to `file.bat` is `UTF-8`. I suppose if the saved encoding were `ANSI` the problem would be solved. How to do this?

Comment: The problem is that the "ANSI" encoding is dependent of your Windows language configuration. Probably for you ANSI = [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Also, use [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead of `data:` URLs.

Comment: Maybe something like `data:text/plain;charset=Windows-1252`?

Comment: At a cmd console window, try `help chcp`.  Also check your editor settings for the encoding it's saving the source files in.  It's probably fine if it's UTF-8 no BOM, but in your specific case, you may also need to be configured to ANSI there as well.

Comment: Good solution. Thank you all.